# How do I make the Globe key disappear from the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, internationalization

I do some dev and testing on the iPhone. Recently, I was testing some localizations and needed to change the language. I've since changed back to English, but now whenever I bring up a keyboard a "globe" key is always near the bottom of the keyboard. This annoys the heck out of me because I keep accidentally tapping it. Any way to turn it off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under Settings > General > Keyboard > International Keyboards you've got a list of all the keyboard layouts available.
To remove the "Globe" key, you need to have only one keyboard enabled.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, you took a long time to take those screenshots ;)

Comment: @gareth yeah, I wasn't really satisfied with the first 1569 screenshots :)